# Check if a list contains the same string with different case

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to come with a query that tells me weather if a list of string matches the input only if the case is different. Please help.

if the input is "animal" then I need to get a true. If the input is "Animal" then I should get a false because the input matches exactly with the case in the items list. I can't say StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase because it always returns a true then.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string abc = "animal";
            List<string> items = new List<string>() { "Animal", "Ball" };
            if (items.Any(x => x.Matches(abc, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("matched");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    static class Extentions
    {
        public static bool Matches(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
        {
            return source?.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) == 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `IndexOf` and comparing to `0` is a bad idea __also__ because if `source` is `"Animalissimo"` and `toCheck` is `"animal"`, then the index returned is `0` because there is a _substring_ starting initially in `source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this if I understand correctly:

```
    if (items.Any(t => abc.Equals(t, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                  t != abc))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("matched");
    }
```

The first part of the if will match the string to check the second will make sure they aren't the same case.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was exactly looking for that.

Comment: Don't do a case-insensitive comparison using `ToLower` - some letters don't tround trip between upper case and lower case. Use one of the `StringComparison.XXXIgnoreCase` comparisons

Answer (score 1):

You can compare twice: case **in**sensitive and case sensitive:

```
if (items.Any(item => abc.Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                      abc.Equals(item, StringComparison.Ordinal))) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("matched");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works.